# need execution time less than a second

Tags: c++

It's a pretty simple program, but i need to make it more efficently
I basically sort an array and at every iteration i calculate a variable based on a formula, and then I get the minimum of those variables

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, n;

    cin >> t;

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        int v[100000];
        cin >> n;
        int s = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> v[i];   
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(v[i] >= v[j])
                {
                    swap(v[i], v[j]);
                    int wand = (j - i + 1) * (j - 1 + 1) * (j - i + 1);
                    s+= wand;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: take int v[100000]; out of the loop, should help a lot.

Comment: still not efficent enough

Comment: You should describe whant you want to calculate exactly

Comment: so, for every iteration where i compare v[i] with v[j] i calculate a value based on the formula (j - i + 1) times 3. i need to calculate the minimum of this values

Comment: Whats your typical n, t values?? Does not look like you can optimize any further programmatically.